# how to add empty folder to abbrevia tar file

Tags: delphi, compression, abbrevia

i want to create a *.tar.gz file with abbrevia, i'm using below code but empty folders are not added to archive. `baseDir` contains empty and not empty folders.

i have found bugs that fixed about empty folders

https://sourceforge.net/p/tpabbrevia/bugs/108/

https://sourceforge.net/p/tpabbrevia/bugs/8/

How can i add these empty folders to archive?

```
  Zip := TAbZipper.Create(nil);
  try
    Zip.BaseDirectory := baseDir;
    Zip.StoreOptions := [soRecurse];
    Zip.Filename := targetFile;
    Zip.FArchive.StoreOptions := [soRecurse];
    Zip.AddFiles('*', faDirectory + faAnyFile);
    Zip.CloseArchive;
  finally
    Zip.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: You might have to actually MODIFY TPABBREVIA to do that.

Comment: @WarrenP, i've done it by using `Jedi`. It seams that code changes should be done to use TPABBREVIA as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did not manage to create an archive that contains empty folder by using `TPabbrevia`. i'm creating archive with `Jedi` and extract it with `TPabbrevia` because `Jedi` does not work to extract tar archive on `Windows 10` properly.

Parameter archiveFileName should contain .tar file extension.

```
function createArchiveFromDirectory(archiveFileName, directory:String):Boolean;
var
  AFormat: TJclCompressArchiveClass;
  Arc: TJclCompressArchive;
  Code: Integer;
  str:string;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    AFormat := GetArchiveFormats.FindCompressFormat(archiveFileName);
    if ( AFormat <> nil )  then
      Begin
        FArchive := AFormat.Create(ArchiveFileName, 0, False);
        str := ExtractFileName(Directory);
        (FArchive as TJclCompressArchive).AddDirectory(str, Directory, True, True);
        (FArchive as TJclCompressArchive).Compress;
      End;
  except
    // exception handling
  end;
  FreeAndNil(FArchive);
end;
```